# Scripting out SQL Server scripts

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We are moving a Dev server to Prod, I'm listing out server level scripts.
till now I have scripted.

1. Server logins, permissions
2. Stored procedures
3. SQL Server Agent jobs
4. Linked servers
5. Missing indexes
6. Orphan users to fix

Is there anything else I need to script out before moving dev to prod, please help me with the scripts.

I have also been told to compare this to a existing prod server settings, can you please help me with the instructions or script to check and compare settings.

Comment: Search term you are looking for is "SQLSERVER migration check list"..Try checking those and see what can be done further

Comment: I think you need to take care of other objects like views , function , trigger ect. you can find relevant list by running below query - select distinct type_desc from sys.all_objects

Comment: I would hope that you are not really just going to push this all out to prod. Since you are uncertain of what to script I can ensure you that several things will get missed. What you should do is stand up a QA environment and test your deployment there. That way you can find the pieces you miss in a stress free zone. Then refresh it and try again until you get it. Then the deployment to prod will go smoothly.

Comment: I would not recommend "promoting" a development server to production. People do terrible things to development servers - do you want some weird leftovers and configuration settings kicking around? Stand up a new instance and set it up cleanly from the start.